# $# behaviour in CSH

Tags: shell, unix, csh

I have noticed a bit of a strange behaviour of $# in CSH. For example

```
set a=(Hello world); echo $#a
```

will output 2 as expected.
Why does $# act differently with combination of environment variables?

```
echo $#PATH
```

will actually output PATH ignoring # I would expect it to output 1.

My guess is that this is just one of those CSH quirks. Nothing in man page about this. Can somebody explain this behaviour? (Please don't bother writing "don't use CSH" comments I wouldn't use it if I didn't have to)

Comment: PATH was created with setenv. Try: setenv a "Hello world". I Could not find a clause in my local csh man page about '#' behaving differently with setenv variables -- just lines describing its behavior with regular set variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$#foo`, where `$foo` is a shell array variable, yields the number of elements in the array `$foo`. If `$foo` is an ordinary non-array variable, `$#foo` yields 1.

csh and tcsh treat shell variables (set by the `set` command) quite differently from environment variables (set by the `setenv` command or inherited from the parent process). The value of an environment variable is always just a string (which is why `$PATH`, for example, needs `:` characters to delimit the list elements).

It would probably be more consistent for `$#FOO`, where `$FOO` is an environment variable, to yield `1` rather than expanding to the value of `$FOO`. In any case, the behavior doesn't seem to be documented, and you should avoid relying on it.

If you specifically want the number of directories in your path, `$#path` will give you that; `$path` is a shell array variable that's automatically tied to the value of the `$PATH` environment variable.

For other variables, you just have to keep track of whether a variable is a shell variable or an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables can't be a list, only variables can, so doing `$#PATH` makes littles sense. It should probably be an error.

If you want to get the length of the path, you can use `$#path`. This will use the special `$path` variable.